# Does bazel support test execution order?

Tags: integration-testing, bazel

I have a certain number of end-to-end integration tests that I'd like to run before other deeper end-to-end tests run. So long as I am not using the `--keep_going` flag the first test failure should quit a `bazel test //...` session. I'd like the more shallow end-to-end tests to run before the deeper tests, is there a way to govern test execution order from bazel?

I suppose I could do stuff in the shell like marking the tests as `manual` and then piecewise invoking the relevant tests in the order I wish, but it would be great if there's some built in way to accomplish the above.

Comment: I want this feature very much!

Answer (score 7):

There's no direct support for this in Bazel, AFAIK.

You could set user specified tags and then use the `--test_tag_filter` flag to run tests in batches. F.e. you could have `shallow` and `deep` tags, and then first run the tests with the `shallow` tag, then the tests without either tag and then the tests with the `deep` tag.

Comment: aha so I'd go something like
`bazel test --test_tag_filter="+shallow,-deep" //foo/...; bazel test --test_tag_filter="-shallow,-deep" //foo/...; bazel test --test_tag_filter="-shallow,+deep" //foo/...`

Comment: Exactly, that's also what I was going to propose. Note that for the last invocation, you can remove the test filter: the bazel cache will be leveraged, and by removing the filter, you have the guarantee all tests execute (e.g. one which has both tags).